iOS Simulators not showing in Xamarin visual studio for mac after updating to Mac OS Sequoia
I recently updated my Mac to Mac OS Sequoia 15.0 and also upgraded my Xcode to 16.
I upgraded my Xamarin Visual Studio for Mac as well but after that the old error starts again of showing No Simulators in iOS.
I tried almost all the things I knew.

Restarted both Visual Studio and Xcode and Mac as well.
Checked all the paths in Xcode Settings.
Build and clean my Visual Studio.
Removed Visual Studio and installed again.
Downloaded command line tools and Developer tools also for Xcode.

Below is my Xamarin visual Studio details.


How can I resolve this?

VSMac is no longer supported.  It will not work with the new version of XCode.  You need to reinstall the prior version

I think this would help to fix your issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/79038670/7620164

I found a temporary workaround for above solution.
Download Xcode15.4 and from your Visual Studio Preferences, set the preferred Xcode to 15.4 not 16 or above as it is not supported.
Now Relaunch the Visual Studio and it will show all the simulators.
Now to link the Xcode Command Line tools to Xcode15.4, we need to open the Xcode 15.4 but since it is not supported with latest version.
Firstly, Right click on Xcode -> Show Package Contents -> Mac OS -> Xcode.
Double click on that Xcode so it will open Xcode15.4. From that Xcode settings, set the Command Line Tools path to Xcode15.4.
Now Rebuild the Project in visual Studio and it should run with all the simulators.
UPDATE : Since I downloaded Xcode16 and Xcode 16.1, I am able to run the app on all simulators.

Hi, I tried this and now I see the simulators, but at compile time I receive this error: MTOUCH : error MT0024: Could not find required file '/Applications/Xcode15.4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator18.0.sdk/SDKSettings.plist'.
I changed to an iOS 17.5 simulator but the error persist.

There are a couple of things happening at once here:

Visual Studio for Mac is no longer supported as of September 2024 (see here)
Xcode 16/iOS 18 is not yet supported by .NET MAUI (see here)

You will want to use VS Code on a Mac to develop you .NET MAUI apps now. Unfortunately, there is no official way to use Xcode lower than version 16 on macOS Sequoia. So either you will need to reformat your machine and use the previous version of macOS and Xcode 15, or you can refer to this blog post to make it work with the current macOS version.
Additionally, for the future you might want to make sure to disable all auto-update mechanisms and keep an eye on this wiki page to make sure all the versions you install are supported and in line.

If you’ve recently upgraded to macOS Sequoia, here’s a recommended solution:

Uninstall Xcode version 16 from your Mac.

Visit the Apple Developer Downloads page and download Xcode version 16 beta 2.

After the download completes, open and install iOS 18.

Close Visual Studio and Xcode, then restart your Mac.

Reopen Visual Studio and Xcode.


it should show the simulators you have.

Note: Double check your xcode simulators.

